# useSelector in child component re-rendering parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react and I'm getting to play with redux but I noticed every time my child component (the icon bag) changes the number of items in the bag the entire header component re renders. I have tried,

- useMemo
- createSelector
- React.memo(Header)

Any suggestions?

[image]

**HEADER COMPONENT**

```
const Header = ({ currentUser }) => {
    const { hidden } = useSelector(state => state.cart);

    return (
        <div className="header">
            ...
            <div className="options">
                ...
                <CartIcon />
            </div>

        </div>);
};

export default Header;
```

**CART ICON COMPONENT**

```
const CartIcon = () => {
    const selectCartItems = createSelector(
        state => state.cart,
        cart => cart.cartItems
    );
    const cartItems = useSelector(selectCartItems);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const totalItemsCount = (cartItems) => {
        return cartItems.reduce((acc, crr) =>
            acc + crr.quantity
            , 0)
    };
    const totalItems = useMemo(() => totalItemsCount(cartItems), [cartItems])

    return (
        <div className="cart-icon" onClick={(() => dispatch(actionCreators.onToggleCart()))}>
            <ShoppingIcon className="shopping-icon" />
            <span className="item-count">{totalItems}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CartIcon;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely because your `state.cart` value is being updated with the items that are in the cart.  `useSelector` forces a re-render whenever the returned reference changes, so `Header` is re-rendering whenever *any* cart data changes.

You should change it to select *only* the data the `Header` component needs:

```js
const hidden = useSelector(state => state.cart.hidden);
```

Comment: That fixed the issue! Thanks Mark! I'm assuming then the useMemo() is not needed but the createSelector() should be left the way I have it?

Comment: I wonder why would someone downvote an answer that solves the OP's problem, +1 from me. I was about to edit my answer but ....

Comment: The `useMemo` is fine as-is, although there's nothing wrong with just recalculating a value like that every time the component re-renders.

Answer (score -1):

In `Header`, if `hidden` changes value, the component will re-render.

Is `dispatch(actionCreators.onToggleCart())` updating `state.cart`?

You should unsubscribe from `hidden` in header to test whether this is causing the re-render.